# Using orWherePivot brings non related models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship

My company has 30 dependencies and each user is associated with a dependency, but they are moved around from time to time, depending on the type of contract, the assignment to a dependency can have a fixed date or can be open (null). I keep track of the dependencies the users were assigned to with a pivot table that stores the dependency_id, the user_id, the date when they were assigned to that dependency and in case the contract date is known or when they are moved or retire from the company, the ended_at column gets a date value.

When I want to know what dependencies has a user been in, I use

```
$user->dependencies;
```

But now I want to know the active dependency for a user, so I built my getActiveDependency method like this:

```
$user->dependencies()
     ->wherePivot( 'ended_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format( 'Y-m-d' ) )
     ->orWherePivot( 'ended_at', null )
     ->first();
```

I explain my query:
The first line is just the query hasMany
The second line will filter all the ones that have an ending date, but it is greater than now
The third line will add to the query the ones with an ended at value of null
The last line gets only the first result because any user can only be assigned to one dependency and there is only one dependency active for any user at a given time.

When I execute the query with the first and second lines or first and third lines, I get the expected results, but when I execute the entire query I get 495results for a user who has only been assigned to one dependency.

Is there a known bug that is causing this?

Am I using a wrong query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try parameter grouping

```php
$user->dependencies()
    ->where(function($query){
         $query->wherePivot( 'ended_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format( 'Y-m-d' ) )
             ->orWherePivot( 'ended_at', null );
    })
     ->first();
```